# Scraping different tables with Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Currently I'm trying to scrape all the price list tables from the website below: 
http://aeroportos.weebly.com/fuel-prices.html#.W7SatGj7Sbj

However, I'm facing some issues in trying to locate the tables in my xpath. Also, I'm not sure if I can scrape all tables in one script, or I will have to go over them manually?

```
def get_prices():
    url = "http://aeroportos.weebly.com/fuel-prices.html#.W7SM3mj7Sbj"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
    rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wsite-content"]/div/table/tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    prices = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        country = cells[0].text
        code = cells[1].text
        name = cells[2].text
        price = cells[3].text
        prices.append(region, country, code, name, price)
    print(prices)
```

Comment: Hi. What "problems" exactly? I see couple of "obvious" issues, like `region` not being defined, `.append()` using multiple arguments - but the main problems would be (I guess) some `NoSuchElementException`s right?
It is risky to find element within another element, without first checking that the parent element is found in the first place.
Can you please share some more info, like some exception that you are getting, or unexpected results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in writing the correct xpath which picks up all the rows with data (without headers) across all the tables present in the page.

The below code is supposed to work well:

```
def get_prices():
    url = "http://aeroportos.weebly.com/fuel-prices.html#.W7SM3mj7Sbj"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)
    rows = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Airport")]/ancestor::tr/following-sibling::tr')
    prices = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        region = cells[0].text
        country = cells[1].text
        code = cells[2].text
        name = cells[3].text
        price = cells[4].text
        prices.append(region, country, code, name, price)
    print(prices)
```

Note: I haven't executed the code but it is supposed to work well. Thanks.